# jquery Hotkeys - enabling a combination while INSIDE a input/textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hotkeys

I'm using the jQuery hotkeys plugin here: https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys

The plugin prevents hot keys from firing when you are inside an input field.

In my case, I want a hotkey to fire when inside an input box, not all but one in particular:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'Shift+return',function (evt) {
        alert('got it')
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how jQuery Hotkeys can be patched to allow for shift+return to be fired when inside an input/textarea field? but not fired for all the other hotkey bindings?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, you can bind the event handler to any expression (not just `document` as in your example).  You could explicitly bind the `shift+return` handler to whatever `input` elements you want by using a selector:

```
$("#test").bind("keydown", "shift+return", function(event) {
    alert('got it');
});
```

Where `test` is the `id` of the `input` you want to listen to for the event.

I have it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vKrM9/

Comment: Did it work in IE9 for you? For me, I get an alert after pressing only Shift.